# Why am I getting a "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myclientunit" exception?

Tags: hibernate, jboss, transactions, jta, persistence.xml

I'm trying to deploy a JAR file on JBoss 4.2.3.GA.  I'm using Hibernate 4.1.5.SP1 and validator 4.3.0.Final.  The Maven dependencies are ...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Here's where it gets good.  I'm getting the exception, "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myclientunit", although in my jar's META-INF/persistence.xml, I have

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="myclientunit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate.cfg.xml" />
            <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</property>
            <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml is as follows …

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:/MySqlDS</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping class="com.parentco.fdr.myproject.model.UserRole" />
        <mapping class="com.parentco.fdr.myproject.model.Organization" />
        <mapping class="com.parentco.fdr.myproject.model.Product" />
        <mapping class="com.parentco.fdr.myproject.model.State" />
        <mapping class="com.parentco.fdr.myproject.model.Country" />
        <mapping class="com.parentco.fdr.myproject.model.AccessCode" />
        <mapping class="com.parentco.fdr.myproject.model.Contract" />
        <mapping class="com.parentco.fdr.myproject.model.TrainingLink" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

any ideas what I'm leaving out?  Below is the complete exception ...

```
14:12:58,470 ERROR [JobRunShell] Job default.job.0.1345057732332 threw an unhandled Exception: 
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myclientunit
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleInCallerTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:87)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:130)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:195)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.localInvoke(MessagingContainer.java:249)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.delivery(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:268)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.invoke(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:138)
    at $Proxy83.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.quartz.inflow.QuartzJob.execute(QuartzJob.java:57)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myclientunit
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:33)
    at org.mainco.subco.dido.service.AbstractHibernateTxnService.startOperation(AbstractHibernateTxnService.java:27)
    at org.mainco.subco.dido.service.OrderServiceImpl.getContractsFromOpportunities(OrderServiceImpl.java:169)
    at org.mainco.subco.dido.quartz.ProcessOrdersWorker.work(ProcessOrdersWorker.java:29)
    at org.mainco.subco.dido.quartz.ProcessOrdersJob.execute(ProcessOrdersJob.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:166)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:126)
    ... 11 more
```

**Edit:** Including my datasource file, located at $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy/mysql-ds.xml ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- $Id: mysql-ds.xml 71535 2008-04-01 07:05:03Z adrian@jboss.org $ -->
<!--  Datasource config for MySQL using 3.0.9 available from:
http://www.mysql.com/downloads/api-jdbc-stable.html
-->

<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>MySqlDS</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/parentco</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>myproject</user-name>
    <password>password</password>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
    <!-- should only be used on drivers after 3.22.1 with "ping" support
    <valid-connection-checker-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name>
    -->
    <!-- sql to call when connection is created
    <new-connection-sql>some arbitrary sql</new-connection-sql>
      -->
    <!-- sql to call on an existing pooled connection when it is obtained from pool - MySQLValidConnectionChecker is preferred for newer drivers 
    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql> -->


    <!-- corresponding type-mapping in the standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml (optional) -->
    <metadata>
       <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Comment: do you have datasource file in jboss?

Comment: Yes, I have included the contents in the question.  Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Add `hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar` (or which version of hibernate are you using) to your libs, and to classpath.
or dependency (if you are using maven)

```
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>3.4.0.GA</version>
```